# Unity C# Поиск объектов в определённом радиусе другого объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема такова: на сцене есть Объект(дровосек) и объекты(деревья, которые я спавню мышкой). Моя задача сделать так, чтобы дровосек направлялся по очереди к каждому дереву. Какой подход тут необходим?

Comment: Можешь при спавне дерева создавать пустой объект и через код прописать движение персонажа к это точке( вроде бы MoveToward, но это не точно) и создать переменную для запоминания поочередности установки деревьев ( при ломании дерева, пустой объект удаляется). Чтобы находить деревья используй Physics.OverlapBox / OverlapCapsule / OverlapSphere. ЛИБО при спавне запоминать координаты и прописывать передвижение персонажа к ним, но в таком случае прийдется использовать много переменных либо массивы\списки или подобные варианты. Я бы сделал как прописано выше в 1 варианте. Приятного Коддинга.

Comment: @Кирилл запиши как отдельный ответ. Ответ-то хороший.

Comment: Павел, отметь тот ответ который больше тебе подошел. Это галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь при спавне дерева создавать пустой объект и через код прописать движение персонажа к это точке( вроде бы MoveToward, но это не точно) и создать переменную для запоминания поочередности установки деревьев ( при ломании дерева, пустой объект удаляется). Чтобы находить деревья используй Physics.OverlapBox / OverlapCapsule / OverlapSphere. ЛИБО при спавне запоминать координаты и прописывать передвижение персонажа к ним, но в таком случае прийдется использовать много переменных либо массивы\списки или подобные варианты. Я бы сделал как прописано выше в 1 варианте. Приятного Коддинга

Answer (score 0):

Находишь деревья по тегу Tree (не забудь теги расставить) при помощи

[Physics.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) / [OverlapCapsule](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapCapsule.html) / [OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) (выбери что больше понравится)

и делаешь что нужно